# Writing mm-aaaa in excel without it changing it by a date

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I must write `mm-aaaa` (`06-2014` for example) in an Excel sheet, but each time I do so, Excel automatically changes my cell format to "personalised" and select a date format.

Writing the value and pressing enter changes the format to custom; changing the format back to General change the date to 41780, which is no good either.

I absolutely need to keep the "General" format and the date to be written as `mm-aaaa` because the file is then going to be read by a python script which I cannot change. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special pasting as text didn't work.

However setting the cell format as text, writing in it then changing it back to standart worked